# Something like background-repeat: repeat-x in Android?

Tags: android, background

I have a question and is this:

In CSS we use background-repeat: repeat-x (or repeat-y) for repeat an image along the page...
so, in Android I can use something like that? I wanna use something like that for my android application :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try whether this suits your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/tile_final"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a [bitmapdrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)
2. set the [tilemode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android%3atileMode) with `android:tileMode="repeat"` (xml) or code [`myBitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeXY%28android.graphics.Shader.TileMode,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use tileModeX="repeat"...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/greco_header_up"
android:tileModeY="disabled"
android:tileModeX="repeat" />
```